# How do you prevent SAS stored process to show the log when users add _debug=log in the url

Tags: sas, sas-stored-process

When you run a SAS Stored Process (STP) with some url parameters

```
https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx?_program=yyy/yyy&aaa=aaa
```

anyone can see the log by adding `_debug=log` in the url parameters.

Is there a way to prevent that possibility?

I would like to hide the log from my users.
(Not only when errors occur, for that cf. http://support.sas.com/kb/16/225.html)

EDIT: I forgot to specify that I'm looking for a solution that would not impact other STP's, only one.

Comment: Your link suggests the following: `One approach is to modify the "web.xml" file and adding a value of "0" for "DebugMask". This will prevent the "Show SAS log" button from being displayed. But, it will also prevent all users from seeing the SAS log even if they specify "_debug=log" when they submit a request.`  Is that impractical?  It seems it does what you want?

Comment: @Joe I believe this would be a solution, but too radical in my case as I don't want to impact other STP on the same SAS server (either from colleagues or myself). I didn't think of this when formulating my question, will edit. Thanks!

Comment: In your STP code can you just add `%let debug=;` ?

Comment: @quentin `%let _debug=;` Just tried to be sure, but no. I think this variable is used at a higher level than the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SAS Enterprise Guide these are the steps that I went through to reject showing the SAS Log running the stp on the web:

1) Right Click to modify the stored process

2) Go into "prompts" and create a new prompt

3) Set the first tab values to this:

[image: Instead of Edit you'll be creating new]

4) In the second tab, select prompt type of "variable"

5) Click to check the default value box and leave the default value blank

[image: define your _debug variable]

Now when a user tries to run the stored process from the web with &_debug=log they should see an error not allowing them to:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to put a `PROC PRINTTO` in your autoexec.sas.  That way the log is redirected from streaming to the client to where ever you specify.  Just make sure you have unique file names for the logs or you can get into trouble with 2 STPs trying to write to the same file.

Comment: Sorry this is not working with STP. The file is empty and you can still see the log on the web.

Comment: works for me.  the log up to the `PROC PRINTTO` is returned, but there is nothing after that.  The file produced has the log below that point.

Comment: I tried again and I see the complete log when adding `&_debug=fields,log` in the url. What I did: I inserted `proc printto print='\\xxx\xx\yyy.log' new;run;` at the top of my STP. (the STP doesn't contain `%stpbegin` nor `%stpend`). The file `yyy.log` is created but is empty, 0kb...

Comment: You want  `PROC PRINTTO log='\\xxx\xx\yyy.log' new;run;` to redirect the log. With `print=` you are redirecting the output, not the log.